# How can I fire SQL query on a HasCachedResult in Snowpark Java

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was writing a program using Snowpark Java and came to a situation where I need to fire a SQL query on a transformed data.

My pipeline looks like this

Read table -> Filter -> Sort -> SQL query -> Write data into another table

I can reach till Sort by

```
Dataframe dfSort = df.filter(Functions.col("EMP_ID").gt(Functions.lit(102)))
                .sort(Functions.col("EMP_NAME"))
```

How do I query on dfSort? or
if I create a HasCachedResult on this dfSort,

```
HasCachedResult dfTemp = dfSort.cacheResult();
```

then also, how can I query on dfTemp as we do not get the name of temporary table created in dfTemp